# Can't launch app on phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I wrote simple app for android, launch it on emulator(Xamarin), all OK.

But when i launch it on phone i have ("Unfortunately "app" has stopped")
What's wrong with my code?

**My xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="267.9dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/fone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/privateButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="98.9dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/logoButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="113.7dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/cart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="142.7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <Button
            android:text="Суші"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/sushi"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:text="Роли"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/rolli"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="142.7dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <Button
            android:text="Сети"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/sets"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:text="Холодні Закуски"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:background="@drawable/holodni"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#f2565c"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/previousButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="143.8dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="17.8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13.8dp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="143.8dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="13.6dp"
                android:clickable="true" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="17.8dp"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**And my Main Activity:**

```html
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Murakami
{
    [Activity(Label = "Murakami", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/logo", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
       // int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            ImageButton next = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.nextButton);
            ImageButton previous = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.previousButton);
            ImageButton home = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.homeButton);

            next.Click += delegate
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MenuActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            //Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            //button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enabled the USB-Debugging Mode on your Android Phone?

Comment: I have .apk in /bin folder and just copy it to phone.

Comment: The result probably require Xamarin shared library (used in debugging). The correct way is to actually connect your phone either through USB debugging or Wifi debugging and start debugging from Xamarin. If you want to have the installable apk, build/publish the project